# Passing variables into single quoted strings in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, string

Hi I am trying to complete a college project for the weekend and have hit a speed bump.

The basic idea of the project is displaying geotagged tweets on google maps using rails and jQuery Mobile. Rather than use the twitter api I opted for the datasift streaming api.

In order for this to work i need to pass a query string to the datasift api which looks like this:

```
'twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius "53.33754457198889,-6.267493000000059:10"'
```

where the geolocation "53.33754457198889,-6.267493000000059" is the centre and the "10" the the radius in miles around which to capture geotagged tweets.

I want to pass variables in the string eg

```
'twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius "#{@users_location}:#{radius}"'
```

but the single quotes mean I can't do this with this string I have tried to concatenate the string in different ways with no joy so if anybody has some advice or a solution I'd appreciate it

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm in the office at the moment, so when I get home I'll run through the answers and get back to you, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `%(` `)` to quote the string, like `%(twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius "#{@users_location}:#{radius}")`.

See [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UB) for some other alternatives you may use.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass variables into single quoted strings, but there are several methods to archieve what you want:

```
# use a double quouted string and escape the quotes inside the string
"twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius \"#{@users_location}:#{radius}\""

# use single quotes and concat several strings
'twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius "' + @users_location + ':' + radius + '"'

# just use single quotes in a double quoted string
"twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius '#{@users_location}:#{radius}'"

# as the other answers suggest use %()
%(twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius "#{@users_location}:#{radius}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `%()` better (the other answer), but you can also escape quotes with `\"` inside a double-quoted string. All this information can be found in nearly any Ruby string tutorial/documentation.

You can also use HERE strings:

```
s = <<FOO
  twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius "#{@users_location}:#{radius}"
FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to escape double quote :

```
"twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius \"#{@users_location}:#{radius}\""
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create the string you need by concatenation.  Something like:

```
 str = "'twitter.geo exists AND interaction.geo geo_radius " + '"' + "#{@users_location}:#{radius}" + '"' + "'"
```

Comment: Ha - when I started answering this, no other answers had been posted. By the time I've finished, I'm just repeating someone else's answer. Hmm ...